# UIImageview aspect fill and clipsToBounds , how to make subview not clipped?

Tags: ios, objective-c, object, uiimageview

```
  UIImageView*  parentView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)];
    parentView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
    parentView.clipsToBounds = YES;

 UIImageView* subview = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-4, 0, 37, 16)];
           [parentView addSubview: subview];
```

***How can subview not being clipped by parentView while parentView must have clipsToBounds to be Yes?***

Comment: What you actually want to do? As if you set the parent clipsToBounds childView will also be clipped.

Comment: @sneha the subview should be displayed out of bounds of parentView , since the parentView could be scrolled so subview must be subview of parent view

Comment: parentView is subview of UIScrollView ?

Comment: @sneha parentView is a view of iCarousel,specifically.

Comment: remove this line parentView.clipsToBounds = YES; It will show your image out of the parentView bounds + you can still scroll the parentView. If you are using iCarousel.

Comment: i tried  it in the sample demo. I have changed the code in "viewForItemAtIndex"    view = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200.0f, 200.0f)];
        ((UIImageView *)view).image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"page.png"];
        view.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;
        
        UIImageView *anotherView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(-10, 0, 30, 30)];
        anotherView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"carLot.jpg"];
        [view addSubview:anotherView];

Answer (score 1):

Answer is No - thats not possible.

From [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIView/clipsToBounds),

> clipsToBounds property
>
> A Boolean value that determines whether subviews are confined to the
>   bounds of the view.
>
> Discussion Setting this value to YES causes subviews to be clipped to
>   the bounds of the receiver. If set to NO, subviews whose frames extend
>   beyond the visible bounds of the receiver are not clipped. The default
>   value is NO.

Answer (score 0):

I’ve solved this by overriding wantsDefaultClipping of the subviews to return NO.

Answer (score 0):

I find **a solution**:

*Make a UIView that has two imageViews as subviews , you can custom these two imageViews separately and they won't bother each other.*

@sneha thanks for your digging.